# Cómo insertar datos en dos tablas relacionadas con php PDO y mysql

Tags: php, mysql, php7

Si alguien tiene un ejemplo.
Les  voy estar agradecido. 
Un saludo.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php ahi puedes aprender un poco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo lo haría con transacciones:

```
$gbd->beginTransaction();
try{
    $id_r = 1;
    $sql_insert1 = 'INSERT INTO a (a_id, a_name) VALUES (:a_id, :a_name)';
    $stmt = $gbd->prepare($sql_insert1);
    $stmt->bindValue(':a_id', $id_r);
    $stmt->bindValue(':a_name', $name);
    $stmt->execute();
    $sql_insert2 = 'INSERT INTO b (a_id) VALUES (:a_id)';
    $stmt = $gbd->prepare($sql_insert2);
    $stmt->bindValue(':a_id', $id_r);
    $stmt->execute();
    $gbd->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $gbd->rollback();
};
```

Siendo $id_r el id que relaciona ambas tablas.

Comment: Genial track3r, tengo entendido que las transacciones también se pueden hacer en mysql

Comment: Tendrás un ejemplo de transacción en mysql.

Comment: Es lo mismo, aquí un ejemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708237/php-mysql-transactions-examples